# Random Walker loop issue for C#

Tags: c#, loops, random, stack, drawing

I am working on a simple Random Walker program that should draw a 10p long line, then choose a random cardinal direction to draw another line (also 10p long) until a certain number of lines have been reached.

I am using four coordinates to draw the line (two coordinates for X and two for Y). The Y coordinates are pushed into a Stack after every line is drawn and they are popped out as the X coordinates. This should ensure that the starting point of every second line is the end-point of the previous line.

The program draws on a Windows Form after pushing a Button controller. As of now, the output is something like this:

[image: Output of program...:-(]

This here is my event handler code block for the button:

```
// Graphics and Pen classes instantiated

        Graphics graphics;
        graphics = this.CreateGraphics();

        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        pen.Width = 1;

        // lineLength is 10 pixels
        // gridLength and gridWidth are needed to keep the Random Path inside a 600×600 field (this is not yet implemented in the code)
        // lineCount is for maximizing the number of lines to be drawn and to control the loop

        int lineLength = 10;
        int gridWidth = 600;
        int gridLength = 600;
        int lineCount = 0;

        // Starting line drawn with the following coordinates:
        int x1 = 20;
        int x2 = 20;
        int y1 = 20;
        int y2 = 30;

        graphics.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        lineCount++;

        // Stack initialized to store "y" coordinates
        // "y" coordinates should be passed on as "x" coordinates for every consecutive lines
        // so that the ending point's coordinate of a line 

        Stack<int> stackY = new Stack<int>();
        stackY.Push(y2);
        stackY.Push(y1);

        for (lineCount = 1; lineCount <= 64; lineCount++)
        {
            // X pops current Y coordinates from stack
            x1 = stackY.Pop();
            x2 = stackY.Pop();

            // Initializing the random number (between 1 and 4) generator to choose from the cardinal directions
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int dir = rnd.Next(1, 5);

            switch (dir)
            {
                // up
                case 1:
                    y1 = y1 + lineLength;   // y1 plus lineLength
                    graphics.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2); //drawing the line
                    stackY.Push(y2);    // pushing the current y coordinates into the stack
                    stackY.Push(y1);
                    break;

                // right
                case 2:
                    y1 = y2 + lineLength; // y2 plus lineLength
                    graphics.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
                    stackY.Push(y2);
                    stackY.Push(y1);
                    break;

                // down
                case 3:
                    y1 = y1 - lineLength; // y1 minus lineLength
                    graphics.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
                    stackY.Push(y2);
                    stackY.Push(y1);
                    break;

                // left
                case 4:
                    y2 = y2 - lineLength; // y2 minus lineLength
                    graphics.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
                    stackY.Push(y2);
                    stackY.Push(y1);
                    break;

            } //switch
        } //for     

    } //event handler
```

I am not really sure what went wrong - I appreciate any heads-up and advices! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: do us and yourself a favor for troubleshooting purposes and change the pen color when you get a random number, that way we can see the lines being drawn. Such as start with black, then red, then blue, then green. Then have the program stop and take a screenshot - it'll be way easier to troubleshoot that than the picture you attached.

Comment: Why are you pushing the `y` values and then using them as `x` values? What you want is to push `x2` and `y2` and then use them as `x1` and `y1` in the next iteration.

Comment: There is no need for a stack at all - just remeber the last endpoint as the starting point for the next line to draw

Comment: I'm guessing using the stack is part of the homework

Comment: startpoint = ... while !enoughlines endpoint = calculateFrom( startpoint ); draw( startpoint, endpoint ); startpoint = endpoint;

Comment: So what's not working? I am confused now.

Comment: I'm with Eduard Malakhov: Visual Studio has a great debugger.  Set a breakpoint at the beginning, step through your program and watch it in action. Look at the variables as they change, and match them to the lines being drawn. You'll learn a lot faster that way, and you'll discover what's going wrong easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making this far more complicated than you need to. Also you are mixing the x and y coordinates in a way that doesn't make sense.

You don't need a stack, just store the most recent points. Something like this.

```
int x = 20, y = 20;
int new_x = x, new_y = y;
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
{
   int dir = rnd.Next(1, 5);
   if (dir == 1) new_x += lineLength;
   if (dir == 2) new_x -= lineLength;
   if (dir == 3) new_y += lineLength;
   if (dir == 4) new_y -= lineLength;

   graphics.DrawLine(pen, x, y, new_x, new_y);

   x = new_x;
   y = new_y;    
}
```

Also you don't need to redeclare the `Random` object every time, just once before the loop.